# flickering of the two child windows <windows.h>

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn GUI in C so im learning the windows.h library. for that im watching a series of video made by a guy. here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWzp0Bbyy_3i750dsUj7yq4JrPOIUR_NK
third video.

*my understanding of the library is very limited and where it happens some problem i dont really know where to start off because by the compiler you dont get any kind of error.*

so here's my problem: im making as you can see at the end of the code two child windows, one that just print a text as static and the other let you enter text in the window, but when i type in the second child window it starts to flicker and i cant see the text that i putted until i highlight it.

````
#include <windows.h>
#define FILE_MENU_NEW 1 //da utilizzare come costante invece di valori lasciati li a caso
#define FILE_MENU_OPEN 3
#define FILE_MENU_EXIT 4

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);

void AddMenus(HWND);
void AddControls(HWND);

HMENU hMenu;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE Hinst, HINSTANCE hPrecInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow)
{
        WNDCLASSW wc = {0};
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
        wc.hInstance = Hinst;
        wc.lpszClassName = L"myWindowClass";
        wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure; 
        ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
    if(!RegisterClassW(&wc))
             return -1;   
        CreateWindowW(L"myWindowClass", L"Cane Porco", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 800, 800, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);  
        
        MSG msg = {0};
        while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,NULL,NULL)){
                        TranslateMessage(&msg);
                        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }        
        return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wp,LPARAM lp){
        switch(msg){
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(wp){
        case 1:
            MessageBeep(MB_OK);
            break;
        case FILE_MENU_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
            case 2:
                MessageBox(NULL,"QUESTA E' UNA PROVA","Prova", MB_OK);
                break;
        }
    case WM_CREATE:
        AddMenus(hWnd);
        AddControls(hWnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
        default:
             return DefWindowProcW(hWnd,msg,wp,lp);
        }
}

void AddMenus(HWND hWnd){
    hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hFileMenu = CreateMenu();
    
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, FILE_MENU_NEW, "New");
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, FILE_MENU_OPEN, "Open");
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, NULL, NULL);
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, FILE_MENU_EXIT, "Exit");
    
    AppendMenu(hMenu,MF_POPUP,(UINT_PTR)hFileMenu,"File");
    AppendMenu(hMenu,MF_STRING,2,"help");   
    SetMenu(hWnd, hMenu);
}

void AddControls(HWND hWnd)
{
    CreateWindowW(L"static",L"Enter Text Here :",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER,300,200,100,50,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"edit", NULL,  WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER |ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,250,250,200,50,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`WM_COMMAND` message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command) is sent not only when menu items are selected or when accelerator keys are pressed. Many controls such as the [edit control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-controls) send it as notification message.

In your message handler, you handle only the menu items. All other `COMMAND_WM`s (and even the menu selections, because the `breaks` there just break out of the inner switch) fall through to `WM_CREATE` and create new controls.

That's where the flicker comes from: When you type something, the edit box is notified, tries to handle the notification `WM_COMMAND` message and creates a new window on top of the one that you were typing in.

You need a `break` for the `WM_COMMAND` after the inner `switch` block.

Comment: thank you so much! i should've thought of it...